# How do I get the public key from my address?

Tags: rpc

I'm developing a bot in python but don't know where to get the public  key of my wallet. How can I generate it?

Comment: https://github.com/satisfywithmylife/phantom-py just see my open source github resp

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing wallet, you'd need to import your private key to get the public key in your code, or instead create a new keypair as a whole. Here's an example of importing your existing public key in [Solathon](https://solathon.vercel.app) library:

```
from solathon import Keypair
ㅤ
wallet = Keypair.from_private_key("your_private_key")
print(wallet.public_key)
```

If you want to instead generate a fresh new Keypair. Then just do:

```
from solathon import Keypair
ㅤ
wallet = Keypair()
print(wallet.public_key)
```